# awk print header information at each line?

Tags: awk

Its possible transform this file with header

```
name,lastname,tall,age
peter,rick,1.8,24
dany,beck,1.7,25
paty,lisp,1.4,45
```

to this

```
name:name,lastname:lastname,tall:tall,age:age
name:peter,lastname:rick,tall:1.8,age:24
name:dany,lastname:beck,tall:1.7,age:25
name:paty,lastname:lisp,tall:1.4,age:45
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) head[i]=$i} 
               {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                    {printf "%s:%s", head[i], $i; if (i<NF) printf ","}
                     print ""}' file
```

If you don't want the header of itself, add `next`:

```
awk -F, 'FNR==1{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) head[i]=$i; next } {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {printf "%s:%s", head[i], $i; if (i<NF) printf ","} print ""}' file
```

Answer (score 4):

You really should give it a little time before accepting an answer so you get a few to choose from.

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
    NR==1{split($0,h); next}
    {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s:%s%s", h[i], $i, (i<NF?OFS:ORS)}
' file
name:peter,lastname:rick,tall:1.8,age:24
name:dany,lastname:beck,tall:1.7,age:25
name:paty,lastname:lisp,tall:1.4,age:45
```

You seem to be doing a lot of text transformations so read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn how to use awk.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few tips.

1. Setting `FS` to `,` would automate the string splitting. Since your every string is split into fields at comma positions, you'd want to set `OFS` to `,` as well, so that commas are printed between all the fields in output.
2. When you have the first string (pattern `NR == 1`), you read the whole field set into an array with indices from `1` to `NF`, and then you know column titles. It even makes sense to store column titles with colons already appended, to not append a colon at each iteration step for every succeeding record.
3. Perhaps it makes sense to output records starting from the second line? Do you really need those strange `name:name` at the top of your output file?
4. Anyway, for every record starting from the second one (pattern `NR > 1`), or even with no limitations (default action, with no pattern), you only have to a) iterate through the whole field set prepending each field with the respective column title, and b) print the whole `$0`.

If you really want the first line transformed and printed, then place the default action AFTER the action from item 2.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==1{split($0,h,",");next}{for(i in h)$i=h[i] ":" $i}1' file
name:peter,lastname:rick,tall:1.8,age:24
name:dany,lastname:beck,tall:1.7,age:25
name:paty,lastname:lisp,tall:1.4,age:45
```

Using `for(i in header)` rather than looping the current record. Downside is that in case data records have more fields than the header record, they are lost. Explained:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }                      # set delimiters
NR==1 { split($0,h,","); next }           # split header to h hash
      { for(i in h) $i = h[i] ":" $i } 1  # loop header, rebuild $0 and print
```